# Lua while loop with multiple conditions

Tags: while-loop, lua

```
while (cyclesc > 0) and (FC = 1 or FC = 3 or FC = 4) do
  --dostuff
end
```

Lua 101 or even coding 101 I'm sure so forgive me - what is best way to write this - nested while loops? seems a waste - is there a way to have multiple conditions in one line of a while loop?

Comment: You should replace `=` with `==`, but other than that it looks just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that out and came back here to share that.

Comment: Now do I mark Joe as the right answer and mark this closed?

Comment: There is no answer to this question yet, so you can write and accept your own (it may take a while before you can accept it).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you've got

```
while (cyclesc > 0) and (FC = 1 or FC = 3 or FC = 4) do
  --dostuff
end
```

which almost works, but you've used `=` instead of `==`. `=` is the variable assignment operator, and `==` compares two values.

Your code should be

```
while (cyclesc > 0) and (FC == 1 or FC == 3 or FC == 4) do
  --dostuff
end
```

*Community wiki as this was solved in the comments*